# Use another URI or route for requests in Playwright

Tags: automation, automated-tests, playwright, playwright-python

Below is my code. When the application is served and the tests start it uses the BASE_URL I pass in await page.goto(BASE_URL). I want to use another route for all my requests.

```
describe("Screenshots - PLAYWRIGHT", () => {
  it("Takes screenshots for multiple browsers", async () => {
    for (const browserType of ["chromium", "firefox", "webkit"]) {
      const browser = await playwright[browserType].launch();
      const context = await browser.newContext();
      const page = await context.newPage();
      await page.goto(BASE_URL);
      await page.waitForLoadState("networkidle");
      await page.screenshot({ path: `screenshots/example-${browserType}.png` });
      await browser.close();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Why is this tagged [tag:playwright-python]? There no Python code here, just JS. As the answer suggests, what's stopping you from just using the route you want?

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid not to understand.
If you need to change the URL you might do exactly that.
What do you want to route?
I am using page.route for blocking purposes for example:

```
   await page.route(
        re.compile(r"((facebook)|(twitter)|(google))"),
              lambda route: route.fulfill(status=404, content_type="text/plain"))
```

Of course you could also do a 301 redirect to another URL,

```
  await page.route("**/*", lambda route: route.fulfill(status= 301, location=NEW_URL)
```

but to me it seems easier to just change the URL for the `page.goto()`